# How to bind parameters for nested query in prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to perform a nested query, but I do not know how to bind the parameters for the prepared statement.

What did I do wrongly, because this doesn't give me my desired output?

The `$dev` contains the correct value already.

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
    $con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'carpark_project');
    $dev = $_SESSION["development"];
    echo $dev;

    $sql = $con->prepare("SELECT *
                          FROM carpark c
                          WHERE c.development IN (SELECT h.development
                                                  FROM history h
                                                  WHERE c.development = ?)"); # Prepare the query

    $sql->bind_param('s', $dev);
    $sql->execute();
    $sql->bind_result($answer);
    $matches = array();

    while ($sql->execute() == true)
    {
        echo "Area: ";
        echo $matches["Area"]."</br>";
        echo "Development: ";
        echo matches["development"]."</br>";
        echo "Lots: ";
        echo $matches["Lots"]."</br>";
        echo "Weekday Rate 1: ";
        echo $matches["weekday1"]. "</br>";
        echo "Weekday Rate 2: ";
        echo $matches["weekday2"]. "</br>";
        echo "Saturday: ";
        echo $matches["sat"]. "</br>";
        echo "Sunday & Public Holidays: ";
        echo $matches["sunph"]. "</br>";
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATED**

I have edited my code and the query seems to be working. However, it prompted me with this error when I run the file.

***updated code***

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
    $con = new mysqli('localhost','root','','carpark_project');
    $dev = $_SESSION["development"]; 
    echo "Development: ";
    echo $dev;


$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT c.Area
FROM carpark c
WHERE c.development IN (
    SELECT h.development
    FROM history h
    WHERE   h.development = ?)"); #prepare the query.this line returns true or false 

$stmt->bind_param('s' , $dev); #now specify that the variables are strings and then add the variables
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($Area);
$matches = array();

if ($stmt->execute() == true)
{
                echo "<br> Area: </br>";
                echo $matches[] = $Area;
                echo "<br></br>";

}

$sql1 = $con->prepare("SELECT c.Lots
FROM carpark c
WHERE c.development IN (
    SELECT h.development
    FROM history h
    WHERE   h.development = ?)"); #prepare the query.this line returns true or false 

$sql1->bind_param('s' , $dev); #now specify that the variables are strings and then add the variables
$sql1->execute();
$sql1->bind_result($Lots);
$matches = array();

if ($sql1->execute() == true)
{
                echo "<br> Lots: </br>";
                echo $matches[] = $Lots;
                echo "<br></br>";

}

$sql2 = $con->prepare("SELECT c.weekday1
FROM carpark c
WHERE c.development IN (
    SELECT h.development
    FROM history h
    WHERE   h.development = ?)"); #prepare the query.this line returns true or false 

$sql2->bind_param('s' , $dev); #now specify that the variables are strings and then add the variables
$sql2->execute();
$sql2->bind_result($wk1);
$matches = array();

if ($sql2->execute() == true)
{
                echo "<br> Weekday(1): </br>";
                echo $matches[] = $wk1;
                echo "<br></br>";

}

$sql3 = $con->prepare("SELECT c.weekday2
FROM carpark c
WHERE c.development IN (
    SELECT h.development
    FROM history h
    WHERE   h.development = ?)"); #prepare the query.this line returns true or false 

$sql3->bind_param('s' , $dev); #now specify that the variables are strings and then add the variables
$sql3->execute();
$sql3->bind_result($wk2);
$matches = array();

if ($sql3->execute() == true)
{
                echo "<br> Weekday(2): </br>";
                echo $matches[] = $wk2;
                echo "<br></br>";

}

$sql4 = $con->prepare("SELECT c.sat
FROM carpark c
WHERE c.development IN (
    SELECT h.development
    FROM history h
    WHERE   h.development = ?)"); #prepare the query.this line returns true or false 

$sql4->bind_param('s' , $dev); #now specify that the variables are strings and then add the variables
$sql4->execute();
$sql4->bind_result($sat);
$matches = array();

if ($sql4->execute() == true)
{
                echo "<br> Sat: </br>";
                echo $matches[] = $sat;
                echo "<br></br>";

}

$sql5 = $con->prepare("SELECT c.sat
FROM carpark c
WHERE c.development IN (
    SELECT h.development
    FROM history h
    WHERE   h.development = ?)"); #prepare the query.this line returns true or false 

$sql5->bind_param('s' , $dev); #now specify that the variables are strings and then add the variables
$sql5->execute();
$sql5->bind_result($sat);
$matches = array();

if ($sql5->execute() == true)
{
                echo "<br> Sat: </br>";
                echo $matches[] = $sat;
                echo "<br></br>";

}

$sql6 = $con->prepare("SELECT c.sunPH
FROM carpark c
WHERE c.development IN (
    SELECT h.development
    FROM history h
    WHERE   h.development = ?)"); #prepare the query.this line returns true or false 

$sql6->bind_param('s' , $dev); #now specify that the variables are strings and then add the variables
$sql6->execute();
$sql6->bind_result($sunPH);
$matches = array();

if ($sql6->execute() == true)
{
                echo "<br> Sun & PH: </br>";
                echo $matches[] = $sunPH;
                echo "<br></br>";

}


?>
</html>
</body>
```

***Error:***

> Development: Mandarin Hotel  Area:
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on
>   boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\SearchLocation.php:41 Stack
>   trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject1\SearchLocation.php on line 41

[Error Sceenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CANJf.png)

Comment: you can't use column name in  select as binding param ..

Comment: `$dev` is what you want to be selecting? Don't you want the `id`s? or why not just join the `history` table?

Comment: @chris85 `$dev` is what I want to select. It is my primary key. I cannot join the `history table` because the **data of this history table** is **from a form that the user input.**

Comment: @scaisEdge `$dev` is not a coluum name. It is a variable with value.

Comment: you can't pass  the object name  ( column or table name ) as param in SQL 
 ..  you should buil th SQL code dinamically but the use of var for this can prioduce a sqlinjection  ..  anyway looking to you code you should know the column you are selecting  ..

Comment: @scaisEdge Sorry, I am very new to PHP and HTML, so I am rather unclear about what you are saying...

However, will this code work instead?

`*$result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM carpark c WHERE c.development IN
SELECT $dev
    FROM history h
    WHERE   c.development = $dev)");
`

Comment: i have posted  an asnwer  with a soggestion that i hope more clear ..

Answer (score 0):

you can't pass the object name ( column or table name ) as param in SQL .. 
you should buil th SQL code dinamically but the use of var for this can produce a sqlinjection

anyway looking to you code you should know the column you are selecting so you could avoid the param for the name pf the column in select eg:

```
$sql = $con->prepare("SELECT *
                      FROM carpark c
                      WHERE c.development IN (
                          SELECT develepment_col /*<<--  assign the proper colname */
                          FROM history h
                          WHERE h.development = ?)"); # Prepare the query
$sql->bind_param('s',  $dev);
$sql->execute();
```

NB  The column and table  .. are special object in SQL and can't be used  as param for buil dinamically SQL code

Comment: I just understood! Thank you! However, I am met with another error. I will update the code above.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the question! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @sciaEdge Understood! I have tried editing already but it still doesnt seem to work. Do you mind looking at my edited codes again?

Comment: i have update the answer  using  h.develpment  = ? instead  of c.development in subquery  .. let me know

Comment: Thank you for your valuable input. I have already tried updating it, but it still shows the same error. I have already updated the questions above! Would greatly appreciate if you could help me solve it! I tried many ways but the error still exists!

Comment: the error "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in  ...." mean that you have an error in your query  .. try check the query in a SQL IDE  coudl be you have some wrong column or table name  ..  and a logical  suggestion if you select development from my_table where development = 1  you should obtain  1 .. there also some logicl issue in your code ..

Comment: sorry that i replied at the wrong segment. I've try the query codes in my sql platform and it is able to work. So i think the problem probably not on the query

Comment: show me a possible value for the $dev content .. is a number or is a string?

Comment: It is a string type. One possible value would be "313@somerset".

Comment: Just tried `mysqli_error($con)` doesn't seem to have problem tho!

Comment: Actually the problem lies in the every bind_param statement `$sql1->bind_param('s' , $dev); #now specify that the variables are strings and then add the variables`